# On MacOS brew service doesn't start on reboot if started as a user

Tags: mac-osx, service, brew

I'm installing a `gitlab-runner` service on MacOS using `brew install gitlab-runner`, after which I can start the service using `brew services start gitlab-runner`. If I start the service with `sudo` (or from the root account otherwise), then after a reboot of the machine, the service will start.

When starting the service without `sudo` - the service will not start after a reboot. There was something about "at login" language in the `brew services help` output, but it both doesn't work when logging in over SSH and also - I want the service to start at boot, even if the user has not logged in.

Any way to get a homebrew "user service" to start at boot on MacOS?

The issue with using `sudo brew start` is that the Gitlab runner service will run the jobs submitted to it as the user that started it - and I need the Gitlab jobs to not run as root.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, the https://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be a better Stack Exchange site for this topic

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption here, but it sounds like you are hoping to get `gitlab-runner` process to run without logging in to a User account on the Mac.
GitLab does not currently support that - https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html

you need to login to a user account on the Mac on run gitlab-runner that way.

> Currently, the only proven way for it to work in macOS is by running the service in user-mode.

GitLab itself admits that it is "less secure" than other methods, i.e. they're admitting you have to turn off FileVault and enable auto-login or be prepared to manually login to the Mac if it shuts off or reboots.

Comment: Unfortunately, "start on login" doesn't actually starts when logging through SSH, and while I would prefer to have this fully automated, logging through SSH is doable, but logging in graphically to start the Gitlab runner is a complete non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `brew` doesn't support running "launch daemons" - it can only manage "launch agents" ([this Apple documentation delves a bit into the difference between "agents" and "daemons"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), though - like most official Apple documentation - falls short of an actual spec), which means either run on boot as root or run on user login as a user.

But there is a way to have services running on boot as a user. I've solved my problem by:

1. Run `brew services start gitlab-runner` (without `sudo`) to cause brew to generate the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist` file that defines the service.
2. Stop the service (`brew services stop gitlab-runner`)
3. Move the file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist`
4. Edit the plist file to add the `UserName` key:

```
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>myuser</string>
```

5. Change ownership of the file to be owned by `root` (otherwise Launchd won't start it): `chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist`
6. reboot

The service would now start on boot and run under the user account specified in the daemon plist file.

#### Sample Use Case

In my use case, I'm using AWS `mac1.metal` "VM" to run the Gitlab runner, and I'm setting up the init script by setting the EC2 "user data" field to a bash script that can set up the Gitlab runner and start it automatically, and it looks something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GITLAB_TOKEN=GET_THE_CI_TOKEN_FROM_SOMEWHERE
# this script runs as root, so to use brew we need to run
# a script as ec2-user:
cat > /usr/local/bin/setup-ci.sh <<<'#!/bin/bash -x
    source .bash_profile
    brew upgrade
    brew update --auto-update
    brew install rbenv gitlab-runner
    rbenv init - bash >> .bash_profile
    source .bash_profile
    rbenv install 2.7.4
    rbenv global 2.7.4
    brew services start gitlab-runner
    sleep 10 # let the service settle before registering
    gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url https://gitlab.com --registration-token "'"${GITLAB_TOKEN}"'" --executor shell --name mac-gitlab-runner --tag-list macos,ios --shell bash
    sleep 3
    cat /Users/ec2-user/.gitlab-runner/config.toml # for debugging
    # update the plist file
    perl -lpe "m,RunAtLoad, and print \"\t<key>UserName</key><string>ec2-user</string>\"" ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist > homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist
    sudo mv homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist
    sudo /usr/sbin/chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist
    # Try to stop service - it sometimes "fails", but we dont care about that
    brew services stop gitlab-runner || true
'
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/setup-ci.sh
su - ec2-user -c /usr/local/bin/setup-ci.sh
```

After the launch complete, I reboot the EC2 instance and Gitlab runner comes up automatically, running as the `ec2-user`.

Comment: are gitlab-runner shell jobs actually executing and working correctly??

Comment: @race_carr Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @race_carr - I added my (almost complete) init script for AWS, for reference.

Comment: huh kudos to you! I hope it continues to work